# Is it possible to extract a list from a table in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have an `org-mode` table

```
| name      | band     |
|-----------+----------|
| lennon    | beatles  |
| mccartney | beatles  |
| harrison  | beatles  |
| starr     | beatles  |
|-----------+----------|
| page      | zeppelin |
| plant     | zeppelin |
| jones     | zeppelin |
| bonham    | zeppelin |
|-----------+----------|
| mason     | floyd    |
| waters    | floyd    |
| wright    | floyd    |
| barrett   | floyd    |
| gilmour   | floyd    |
```

I'd like to programmatically extract the following list from this table:

```
* Beatles
  + lennon
  + mccartney
  + harrison
  + starr
* Zeppelin
  + page   
  + plant  
  + jones  
  + bonham 
* Floyd
  + mason   
  + waters  
  + wright  
  + barrett 
  + gilmour
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is an example using elisp, and assumes your table is correctly grouped by artist:

```
#+NAME: db
| name      | band     |
|-----------+----------|
| lennon    | beatles  |
| mccartney | beatles  |
| harrison  | beatles  |
| starr     | beatles  |
|-----------+----------|
| page      | zeppelin |
| plant     | zeppelin |
| jones     | zeppelin |
| bonham    | zeppelin |
|-----------+----------|
| mason     | floyd    |
| waters    | floyd    |
| wright    | floyd    |
| barrett   | floyd    |
| gilmour   | floyd    |

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x=db[1:-1] :results raw :hlines yes
  (let ((title nil)
        (output ""))
    (dolist (line x)
      (if (eq line 'hline)
          (setq title nil) ;; mark new section
        (unless title
          (setq title (cadr line))
          (setq output (concat output (format "* %s\n" title))))
        (setq output (concat output (format "  - %s\n" (car line))))))
    output)

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
* beatles
  - lennon
  - mccartney
  - harrison
  - starr
* zeppelin
  - page
  - plant
  - jones
  - bonham
* floyd
  - mason
  - waters
  - wright
  - barrett
  - gilmour
```

On every hline, `title` is set to `nil` to mark a new section. On each new section, the heading is generated.

Note that all output is added to the `output` string directly in org-mode format.